# Docker lumen app throwing php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, lumen

I'll start by saying that I am brand new to Docker. I am trying to do a proof of concept for Docker with an existing Lumen microservice but can't seem to get the mysql container on my local to work properly.

When I run php artisan migrate, I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  # Nginx
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - .docker/nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
      - php

  # Database
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:5.7.24
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
    - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: local_mysql_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: partners

  # PHP
  php:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

And my Dockerfile for the php image

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y git libpng-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev zip \
 && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
 && docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo_mysql \
    gd \
    zip \
 && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer \
  | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN composer install

RUN php artisan migrate
```

I am using the following in my .env file for the DB connection

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=partners
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=local_mysql_password
```

I have tried tweaking the port, changing the service name, container_name, links/depends_on settings, and a handful of other things I can't recall at the moment. I have tried multiple solutions from here, reddit, and github but none have worked. Is there something basic I am overlooking?

Comment: Are all containers runnings? What's the output of `docker ps`? Does error message has any other details like the hostname which it tries to connect to?

Comment: Doesn't look like the containers are running since `docker ps` shows no containers. I'm guessing because the `docker-compose up -d --build` fails it doesn't finish creating the containers? And no there isn't a hostname in the error message. Not a lot of info there.

Comment: I would first try to disable migration and ensure that all containers start up successfully. Then verify that you can connect to the database from the host machine. After that you could try logging into you `php` container with `docker exec -it <container name> bash` and try pinging your `db` container, running migration.

Comment: I ran a simplified version of your docker-compose file, logged into `php` container and managed to ping `db` host. Then I installed MySQL client and managed to connect to the database. Are you sure you have specified correct database host name?

Comment: Ok got it working now. So I commented out the migration and discovered there was a conflict on port 3306 (I have my current local dev environment using that for now). I updated the port in the docker-compose file to be 9906:3306. Still got some errors like I did earlier when I tried this port set up. Turns out that when I changed the port in docker to be 9906:3306, I wasn't supposed to update the settings in Lumen to point to port 9906. I guess linked containers uses the original port (3306) and my computer accesses the container with the mapped port (9906)?

Comment: That makes sense. When you specify port mapping you map a port from you host machine to a port inside Docker container. So unless you need access database inside container you don't really need port mapping - similar to how it works for nginx and php.